# Matlab: Initial Positions of Particles In Space

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a cube whose side are length L. Inside of this cube is a smaller one, and is at the center. Evenly space along this inner cube, I would like to place particles. I have the matrix 'walker', which is a three dimensional matrix that stores the the position of the particle at regular time steps. Specifically, walker(i,j,k) is the information of the i-th particle, at the time step j, and the i-th particle's k-position, where k=1,2, and 3, which represent the x,y and z direction.

Here is my attempt at giving each particle an initial position:

```
L=16
W=5 %Number of walkers (particles)

%Initial Positions of Walkers (particles):
for i=1:W
    for j=1:3
    walker(i,1,j) = L/2 + i - 1;
    end
end
```

However, this just places each of the particles along a straight line. Could someone give me some suggestions as to how I might accomplish this?

EDIT:

```
x=linspace(0,L,W);
y=linspace(0,L,W);
z=linspace(0,L,W);

[X Y Z] = meshgrid(1:L,1:L,1:L);
xyz = [X(:),Y(:),Z(:)];
xyz = cat(1,xyz(:,[1 2 3]),xyz(:,[2 3 1]),xyz(:,[3 1 2]));
xyz = unique(xyz,'rows');

plot3(xyz(:,1),xyz(:,2),xyz(:,3),'.')

axis([-L L -L L -L L])
```

Comment: Do you want to place particles at different positions inside the cube? Also does it matter if it is integer or real number output?

Comment: Yes, I would like to place particles along the inner cube. I am not sure if it matters at this point whether they are integers or real number outputs, just so long as they are evenly space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, this will place points along the inside of the cube evenly:

```
x = linspace(-L,L,5);
y = linspace(-L,L,5);
z = linspace(-L,L,5);

[X Y Z] = ndgrid(x,y,z);
xyz = [X(:),Y(:),Z(:)];
xyz = cat(1,xyz(:,[1 2 3]),xyz(:,[2 3 1]),xyz(:,[3 1 2]));
xyz = unique(xyz,'rows')
plot3(xyz(61:65,1),xyz(61:65,2),xyz(61:65,3),'.'), grid on
axis([-L L -L L -L L])
```

x, y and z will be 5 evenly spaced points from -L to L. This will give you 5^3 = 125 points but you can choose which points you want in pairs of 5 from the xyz matrix. The image for the plot is shown below:

[image]

This is 5 evenly spaced points vertically along the origin. The pairs in xyz start from 1:5, then 6:10, etc. You can choose the pairing that works best for you.

Comment: When I translated this to my code, it created more particles than the number W. I edited my post to include my code that resembles yours; if you could take a look, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yes I will look at it you want only 16 particles?

Comment: Actually, I would like it to work with W amount of particles, where the W stands for walker.

Comment: I updated my answer. This may not be exactly what you want but this should definitely point you in the right direction! What is important is the evenly spaced points using linspace. The 5 give you 5 evenly spaced points and the meshgrid will create these points in all dimensions of the cube. You can pick from xyz which points you would like. It may take some experimenting but that is part of learning. Hope it helps!